# MongoDb Ubuntu 22.04 AMD X64 failed core=dumped status=ILL

Tags: linux, mongodb, lts, jemmy

How to install mongoDb in linux AMD x64. Is it possible?

I've tried install different versions of mongodb. Tried install with .deb file from official website. I tried all commands from different sources step-by-step.

If it is possible please write detailed instructions, because I'm not linux expert